# Extend functionallity of a class: inheritance or java's dynamic proxy

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented

Currently I have three classes and respective interfaces and respective builders:

- **Tree**: the data structure (implemented in `SimpleTree`)
- **ProbabilityTree**: is a `Tree` with added functionality to randomly select child nodes and to adjust the probability of selecting a node (implemented in `ProbabilityTreeImpl`).
- **DynamicTree**: is a `ProbabilityTree` which dynamically constructs nodes when a requested node doesn't exist yet.

The client code needs Trees that support both random selection of nodes, as provided by `ProbabilityTree`, and the tree dynamically growing when yet unexisting nodes are requested, as provided by `DynamicTree`.

*NOTE: Currently all three trees are immutable after having been build; for `DynamicTree` this means clients cannot add or remove nodes, but the tree itself can automatically change.*

*NOTE: See [Github gist with the five Java classes](https://gist.github.com/3348924) for the code.*

There are at least two issues with this design:

1. `DynamicTree` is derived from `ProbabilityTree`, while conceptionally these two capabilities are unrelated (i.e. orthogonal).
2. Using inheritance to add functionally is often considered "bad design" (correct me if I'm wrong here).

---

An alternative design would be to decouple `ProbabilityTree` and `DynamicTree` using something similar to the decorator and/or adapter pattern.  Using Java's dynamic [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) might enable "decorators" that extend the interface and that can decorate other `Tree`s with extended interfaces; i.e.:

```
TreeDecorator implements InvocationHandler, ... {
    Tree adapted;
    ...
    Object invoke(Method method, Object[] args) {
        if( «this class can/should handle method» ) {
            return method.invoke(this, args);
        } else if ( «this.adapted can/should handle method» ){
            return method.invoke(adapted, args);
        }
    };
}
```

Again there are some issue's:

1. Using `Proxy` makes the code more difficult to understand.

What shall I do? Use inheritance to extend functionallity, use dynamic proxy, or something else?

Comment: Why does `DynamicTree` extend `ProbabilityTree` if they are unrelated?

Comment: @Baqueta good question, I need trees that support both random selection of nodes, as provided by ProbabilityTree, and that dynamically grow when an yet unexisting node is requested, as provided by DynamicTree.  To have both capabilities in the first design DynamicTree extends ProbabilityTree.

Comment: How about just putting the functionality shared by both `ProbabilityTree` and `DynamicTree` into a new interface?

Comment: Can you explain that?  Currently the common functionality of `ProbabilityTree` and `DynamicTree` is in `Tree`.  And minimal interface that the client code requires of `ProbabilityTree` and `DynamicTree` are the public methods of `DynamicTree` of the first design alternative. (These methods could easily be extracted into a real interface and I probably will do so)

Comment: I think I'm failing to understand why the `DynamicTree` and `ProbabilityTree` concepts are unrelated when it sounds like you want `DynamicTree` to be a specialised type of `ProbabilityTree`. Are you thinking that at some point you might have a variant of `DynamicTree` which isn't a `ProbabilityTree`?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  But perhaps I should leave it to my future self to deal with that case.

Comment: I think that's a good idea - YAGNI should be applied here :-)

Comment: Agreed, YAGNI for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 reasonable options, depending on what you really need (right now), and how complex your code is.

(What you currently call `DynamicTree`, I call `DynamicProbabilityTree`)

1. If the only thing you really need is a `DynamicProbabilityTree`, and you feel like your code is simple enough to fit in one class, put all your code inside `DynamicProbablityTree`, and get rid of your other classes.
2. If the only thing you really need is a `DynamicProbabilityTree`, but you feel like you code is too complex to fit into one class, keep your code for the tree structure in `SimpleTree`, and put the dynamic and probability code in `DynamicProbabilityTree`. I would recommend that `DynamicProbabilityTree` contain and delegate to a Tree instead of inheriting; inheriting would also work.
3. If you really need a `SimpleTree`, `ProbabilityTree` (that is not dynamic), `DynamicTree` (that does not do probability), and `DynamicProbabilityTree`, use the Decorator pattern.